# Using a calculated field value from a form text box in a query

Tags: ms-access

I have a calculated text box on a form. How can I use that value in a query? The value is based on many other calculations done on the form as well.
I was hoping I wouldn't have to re-do all the calculations in the query.

Answer (score 0):

Providing the form remains open when the query is evaluated, you can reference the value of any control on the form using the following syntax in your query:

```sql
Forms![Your Form Name]![Your Control Name]
```

In the case of referencing the value held by a control on a subform, consider that the subform is just another control on the parent form, and so the chain of references becomes:

```sql
Forms![Your Form Name]![SubForm Name].Form![SubForm Control Name]
```

You can test the value obtained by simply creating a new query in Access with the SQL code:

```sql
select Forms![Your Form Name]![Your Control Name] as FormValue
```

When run, this will yield a single record displaying whichever value was held by the control `Your Control Name` on the open form `Your Form Name` at the time of execution.

Comment: So, the form I have is used to calculate the cost of installing a new kitchen. Once all required items are input on the form, it saves to a table. The table doesn't save any of the calculated fields, that is all done on the form. Your suggestion works, but only for the current customers for which the form is open on.  I would like to do a query which pulls all of the customer quote numbers with the value of the quote.

Comment: Then you'll need to perform the calculation on a record-by-record basis, either within the query or using a VBA function - the form will only present a single (current) value to the query.

Comment: Thanks for your input